# Forcing printing from Quick Look or Finder to open the print dialog

Tags: finder, preview, printing, quicklook

When I print from Preview, the print dialogue opens so I can choose settings. When I print from Quick Look (either from the menu or cmd-P), it doesn't; it automatically sends to the printer. When a document is visible on my screen, I often forget that I haven't opened it in Preview, so I go to print it and then have to quickly cancel the print (because I rarely want to print with default settings; I always want to tweak paper stock, set to 100%, or similar).

Is there any way to set the behaviour in Quick Look to match Preview? Failing that, could I set up a dialogue box to say 'are you sure you want to print directly from the Finder rather than opening this in Preview'? Or any other bright ideas?

I've seen a suggestion to disable cmd-P in Finder completely  but I don't think that would help for the times I do file...print.